# QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer not automatically applied after added

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

### Summary

I am trying to apply a Single Band Pseudo Color Renderer (SBPCR) to a raster layer, importing the shader from an XML. I've hit a dead end trying to get my SBPCR to apply.

- QGIS Version - 3.4.5
- Mac OS X v10.14.4
- Python 3.6

### Problem

Unlike my hillshade raster which, upon being added to the renderer *seems* to refresh automatically, this does not happen with my SBPCR renderer.

**Code Example**

```
def add_color_gradient_raster(color_gradient_rlayer):
    # Import Color Ramp
    my_qfile = QFile("/Hydro1/top_15lev.xml.xml")
    my_qdom = QDomDocument()
    my_qdom.setContent(my_qfile, False)
    my_raster_shader = QgsRasterShader()
    my_raster_shader.readXml(my_qdom.documentElement())
    # Single Band Pseudo Color Render Created
    sb_pseudo_color_renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(
    color_gradient_rlayer.dataProvider(),
    1,
    my_raster_shader)
    sb_pseudo_color_renderer.setOpacity(0.6)
    color_gradient_rlayer.setRenderer(sb_pseudo_color_renderer)
    # Add layer into project
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(color_gradient_rlayer, False)
    layerTree = iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().rootGroup()
    layerTree.insertChildNode(3, QgsLayerTreeLayer(color_gradient_rlayer))
```

### Output

[image: Example Output after adding color gradient]
As seen above I have reason to believe that the problem is not in the creation of the renderer.

- The layer is successfully created and the renderer's opacity is set.
- Upon editing the layer's properties all options seem to be set
  correctly (including the imported colours) and I only need to hit
  apply/ok.

How do I "apply" these settings?

I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score -1):

Use triggerRepaint() on mapLayer